# Android Java - Dropdown spinner sets the same text always, only want to change background color

Tags: java, android, colors, spinner

I have 2 dropdown spinners that I would like to be color coded. I would like 1 to always be labeled as Apple and the other to be Banana. I'm using the dropdown menu to change the background color of the spinner. How do I set the text to always stay as Apple and Banana, but only have the background color of the spinner change based on what is selected? Whenever I use the dropdown to select a color, it changes the text to the color I selected. I feel like I would need a setText function somewhere...

Here is my code so far:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dropdown1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    dropdown2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    String[] colors = new String []{"red", "blue", "green"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, colors);

    dropdown1.setAdapter(adapter);
    dropdown2.setAdapter(adapter);

    dropdown1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            text1 = dropdown1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (text1.equals("red")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
            } else if (text1.equals("green")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
            } else if (text1.equals("blue")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }

    });
```

Comment: What are you getting right now?

Comment: "How do I set the text to always stay as Apple and Banana, but only have the background color of the spinner change based on what is selected?" what text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code,

```
dropdown1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
            text1 = dropdown1.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if (text1.equals("red")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (text1.equals("green")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else if (text1.equals("blue")) {
                dropdown1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question properly. Right now,

```
String[] colors = new String []{"red", "blue", "green"};
```

Is the spinner text, so you want to change it to:

```
String[] colors = new String []{ "Apple", "Apple", "Apple" };
```

Next, instead of

```
text1 = dropdown1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

change it to:

```
int color = dropdown1.getSelectedItemPosition();
```

I recommend using constants or enums for the colors you would like.

I think there are better solutions (not using a spinner), but without context hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Why the change to "Apple"?

Comment: I probably didn't understand the question correctly. He said he wanted to have the text always Apple or Banana (I presumed he was referring to the spinner drop-down text).

Comment: I missed that part. I don't really understand the question at all, actually.

Comment: Yup the wording was quite peculiar and the op hasn't made any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the selected item is already passed as a parameter to `onItemSelected()`, so there is no need to call `getSelectedItem()`. Secondly, the selected item is a `View`, so calling `toString()` on it gives *a text representation of the `View` object*. This is not the same as the text which is displayed the view. Instead, you need to call `getText()`. Putting this all together means you should change

```
text1 = dropdown1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

to

```
String text = selectedItemView.getText().toString()
```